# Uplift modeling with targeted experimental data

Tags: causality, marketing, uplift

I am trying to set up a marketing campaign for cross-selling purposes of a specific product. Since the campaign has already been launched on a subset of customers, based on certain characteristics arbitrarily chosen by the Marketing department, I already have some results in terms of experimental data.

I would like to make use of such experimental data to set up an uplift model to better target the *persuadable* segment of the customer base (I am thinking of something like the meta-learners from `causalML` package).

Now, my question is: can I use such experimental data even if the treatment was not completely randomly assigned? And if so, how exactly?

Thanks in advance for any contribution.

Comment: The way you're describing it, it sounds like a transportability problem to me: you estimate an effect in one population (chosen by Marketing) and you want to transport that effect to another population that did not participated in your experiment. Luckily, this problem perfectly aligns with effect estimation - replacing "confounders" with "effect modifiers", and "treatment assignment" with "selected to the sample", so you can use the same methods for causal inference. See an overview here: [https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.11904](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.11904)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for the very interesting article @ehudk. I think that framework can fit quite well to my use case. I am also experimenting a bit with the models in the econML library by Microsoft, which allows to control for confounding variables in a context of causal modeling. If I understood correctly, my confounders should be the variables selected by Marketing to target the campaign.